2 LEFT OUTER JOINs with UNION
SELECT  tb1.id, tb1.start, tb1.end, tb1.name, 
        tb1.code, ROUND  (Try_cast(tb2.Value as float),0) AS variable1 
FROM    tb1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.ID
AND tb2.Descript LIKE '%Something%'
WHERE     (tb1.star >= 0)
ORDER BY... 

This code works. I select values from table 1 and add a variable1 from table 2.
I need to add another variable from table 2. I tried just to copy it (meaning 2x ROUND... as... + 2x LEFT OUTER JOIN which just took values only for variable1. UNION executes, but it does not add another column for variable2.
SELECT  tb1.id, tb1.start, tb1.end, tb1.name, 
        tb1.code, ROUND  (Try_cast(tb2.Value as float),0) AS variable1 
FROM    tb1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2
ON tb1.id = tb2.ID
AND tb2.Descript LIKE '%Something%'     

UNION ALL

SELECT  tb1.id, tb1.start, tb1.end, tb1.name, 
        tb1.code, ROUND(Try_cast(tb2.Value as float),0) AS variable2
FROM    tb1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2
ON tb1.id = tb2.ID
AND tb2.Descript LIKE '%Somethingelse%' 
WHERE     (tb1.star >= 0)
ORDER BY...


Sample data would help a lot. From the question it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. How to get the result you want depends on the structure and properties of your data (... hence the request for sample data). But syntactically there is nothing wrong with select t1.id, t2_something.value + t2_something_else.value from t1 left join t2 as t2_something ON t1.id = t2_something.id AND t2_something.descript like '%Something%' left join t2 as t2_something_else ON t1.id = t2_something_else.id AND t2_something_else.description like '%SomethingElse%' .

with a UNION the number of columns have to match and the name derives from the first so perhaps NULL AS variable2 to the first and NULL AS variable1 to the second?

Which dbms are you using?

How to get matching data from another SQL table for two different columns: Inner Join and/or Union?

SELECT 
    tb1.id, tb1.start, tb1.end, tb1.name, 
    tb1.code,
    ROUND(TRY_CAST(tb2.Value AS FLOAT), 0) AS variable1,
    NULL AS variable2
FROM tb1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2
    ON tb1.id = tb2.ID
    AND tb2.Descript LIKE '%Something%'     

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    tb1.id, tb1.start, tb1.end, tb1.name, 
    tb1.code,
    NULL AS variable1,
    ROUND  (TRY_CAST(tb2.Value AS FLOAT), 0) AS variable2
FROM tb1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2
    ON tb1.id = tb2.ID
    AND tb2.Descript LIKE '%Somethingelse%' 
WHERE
    tb1.star >= 0
ORDER BY
    ...


Code-only answers are poor. Explain what the problem was & why this solves it. [answer] Except that the question is unclear so it merits downvotes, closing & comments asking for clarification, not answers. [ask] [Help] PS More re using the site: [meta] [meta.se]

You can try with case when..
When you do with union all, it will take first resultset schema and hence you are always getting variable1.
You can also do with union by name but not sure if all databases support this union by name.
Below is the reference query using case when,which you can try, please correct if any syntactical error for case stmt.
SELECT  tb1.id, tb1.start, tb1.end, tb1.name, tb1.code,
case 
    when tb2.Descript LIKE '%Something%' then ROUND  (Try_cast(tb2.Value as float),0) AS variable1 end,
case 
    when tb2.Descript LIKE '%Somethingelse%' then ROUND  (Try_cast(tb2.Value as float),0) AS variable2
FROM  tb1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.ID
Where (tb1.star >= 0)
ORDER BY...

